# Jupyter Notebook で Arduino を用いてグラフのリアルタイム表記を行う

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, arduino

Pythonを用いて、Arduinoとの通信を行いたいのですが、以下を実行しても、グラフがリアルタイムで表示されないです。具体的には実行終了後にしか表示されません。
イメージとしてはアニメーションのように表示されてほしいのですが、どこが原因なのでしょうか？
Windowsを用いています。なにかあればご指摘いただきたいです。

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import serial
from serial.tools import list_ports
import time

ser = serial.Serial("COM6",9600)  # COMポート(Arduino接続) 
xlim = [0,100]
X,Y = [],[]
figure = plt.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
start = time.time()

while True:
    plt.cla()   #前のグラフを消去
    volt = ser.readline().rstrip()   # シリアル通信で受け取った情報（文字列）を改行コードがくるまで代入します。byte型で得る
    volt = volt.decode()
    volt = float(volt)
    Y.append(volt)
    X.append(len(Y))
    
    if len(X) > 100:
        xlim[0]+=1
        xlim[1]+=1
    ax.plot(X,Y)
    plt.title("voltage(cds)")
    plt.ylim(0,5)
    plt.xlim(xlim[0],xlim[1])
    
    if time.time() - start > 20:
            ser.close()
            break
```

Comment: WindowsでもJupyterNotebookでも無さそうですが、この記事は見てみましたか？ [Arduino で測定したデータを Matplotlib でリアルタイムプロット](https://org-technology.com/posts/matplotlib-realtime-plot.html) 他にもこんな記事があるので参考になるかも。[Matplotlib を使用してデータをリアルタイムでプロットする方法](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/matplotlib/how-to-plot-in-real-time-using-matplotlib/), [matplotlibでリアルタイム描画](https://qiita.com/hausen6/items/b1b54f7325745ae43e47), [pythonで3D, 2Dのリアルタイムグラフを作る](https://qiita.com/bridget462/items/710cd42b3ee1f8780260)

Answer (score 0):

この後にされた質問の方に先に答えましたが、こちらも同様に`plt.pause(interval)`を追加することでリアルタイムなグラフ表記が出来るようになるでしょう。

ただやはりJupyter Notebook環境の影響は不明なので、まず素のPythonで試してみてください。
以下に追記箇所だけ抜粋します。

```
    plt.ylim(0,5)
    plt.xlim(xlim[0],xlim[1])
    plt.pause(0.1)             #### この1行を追記
    
    if time.time() - start > 20:
```